# In C# can you split a string into variables?

Tags: c#, string

I recently came across a php code where a CSV string was split into two variables:

```
list($this->field_one, $this->field_two) = explode(",", $fields);
```

I turned this into:

```
string[] tmp = s_fields.Split(',');
field_one = tmp[0];
field_two = tmp[1];
```

Is there a C# equivalent without creating a temporary array?

Comment: You could split it yourself... but basically, other than that, no. (Do you really need separate variables, or could you just keep the array? Why do you want to avoid the array anyway?)

Comment: field_one = s_fields.Split(',')[0];

Comment: There are so much things to be improved in PHP, it's a pitty they focus on such useless (or let's call it very specific) functionalities...

Comment: You would have to write your own StringTokenizer, so you can avoid the creation of the array, but why?

Comment: @JonSkeet I liked the concept of just defining the list of variables on the left with their order being the index of the array. It seemed tidy and I wondered if the same was possible. I am trying to also keep code as close to the original as possible.

Comment: @PhilHannent: If this is really just a matter of syntax, then the answer is a simple "no, there's nothing like this in C#."

Comment: One-liner: `s_fields.Split(',').Zip(new Action<string>[]{x => {field_one=x;}, x => {field_two=x;}}, (x,y)=>{y(x); return default(object);}).ToList();`. Seriously, there is no better method in .NET that splits a string without using an array, except for character manipulation and p/invoke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jon Skeet said the right thing. GC will do the thing, don't you worry.
But if you like the syntax so much (which is pretty considerable), you can use this, I guess.

```
public static class MyPhpStyleExtension
{
    public void SplitInTwo(this string str, char splitBy, out string first, out string second)
    {
        var tempArray = str.Split(splitBy);
        if (tempArray.length != 2) {
            throw new NotSoPhpResultAsIExpectedException(tempArray.length);
        }

        first = tempArray[0];
        second = tempArray[1];
    }
}
```

I almost feel guilty by writing this code. Hope this will do the thing.

Comment: My eyes! Now go and sit in the corner and think about what you've done. ;)

Comment: I am not using the code, but I have to accept your answer because you point to Jon's comments to me and provide a proof of concept for others.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your quite narrow question is no. C# does not provide a 'multi-assignment' capability, so you cannot extract an arbitrary set of values from anything (such as `Split()`) and break them out into individual named variables.

There is a workaround for a specific number of variables, by writing a parameter with `out` arguments. See @vlad for an answer based on that.

But why would you want to? C# provides an impressive range of features that will allow you to take apart strings and deal them with the parts in a such a wide range of different ways that the lack of 'multi-assignment' should barely be noticed.

Parsing strings usually involves other operations such as dealing with formatting errors, trimming white space, case folding. There could be less than 2 strings, or more. Requirements could change over time. When you are ready for a more capable string parser, C# will be waiting.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following approach:

-Create a class that inherits from dynamic object.

-Create a local dictionary that will store your variables values in the inherited class.

-Override the TryGetMember and TrySetMember functions to get and set values from and into the dictionary.

-Now, you can split your string and put it in the dictionary, then access your variable like:

```
dynamicObject.var1
```